# Активирование файла по средством JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, алгоритм

Есть функция JS

```
$('.form_calc .btn_wrap .btn-download').click(function(){
        //Скачать предложение
        var path = '/pdf/pdf.php';
        var formData = $("#form").serialize();
        formData += "&action=download";
        var success = function( response ){
            if (response.status == "OK") {

                /*if (typeof (window.open) == "function") {
                    window.open(response.message);
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = response.message;
                }*/
                //alert (response.message;);
                window.location.href = response.message;
            }
            else {
                alert (response.message);
            }
        }
        $.post(path, formData, success, "json");

        return false;

    });
```

Она должна задействовать файл 'pdf.php'

```
<?php 

require_once('../dompdf/autoload.inc.php');     

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$html = '../index1.html';
$content = file_get_contents($html);
$dompdf->loadHtml($content);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

При просмотре сайта через F12->Network файл включается по нажатию кнопки. Но содержимое не работает. Думаю смог описать проблему

Comment: И чему равен `response.message`?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста в вопросе, что вы имеете в виду под 'файл включается' и 'содержимое не работает'

Comment: @KirillKorushkin | Содержимое не работает = PHP файл должен генерировать pdf файл и скачать его юзеру, но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не запускается.
| 
Файл включается = При просмотре кода страницы в браузере, окошко Network показывает что PDF.PHP работает(то есть он появляется в окошке Network при нажатии на кнопку)

Comment: И куда вы ожидаете перехода в `window.location.href = response.message`? На урл `Successful`?

Comment: @u_mulder сори не то написал там это стоит 'message' => '../intercompforme2/pdf/download.php'